# read values from website continuously at particular time interval in android

Tags: android, time, intervals, http-get

I am new to android. I had a search and found to post and get response from website. What i need is to read a response from website continuously at a particular time interval. For Example reading weather information and alert to the users. please help me out.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: i need to give respond to some hardware device when the weather is cool or hot. if hot means switch on fan or Ac something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a start you can take a look at [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful). Then take a look at [FluentHttpBuilder](http://code.google.com/p/httpclient-fluent-builder/). And the rest is to glue them together :)